# What is the difference between an JSONP request and AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I've been digging for an answer to the above solution, but I did not found something interesting.
Can you guys please explain it in clear words??

Comment: You read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is a generic term that means "Making an HTTP request and processing its response, from JavaScript, without leaving the page".

JSONP is [a specific means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) of making an Ajax request that is performed by adding a `<script>` element that loads an external JavaScript program that does nothing except call a specified function with some data as the first argument. It is a hack to get around the Same Origin Policy. (It is obsolete in the face of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which provides a much safer, and more refined, means to do the same thing).

Comment: "Ajax" is also used in a narrower sense to mean an `XMLHttpRequest`.